# How convert select html tag to Html.DropDownList?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

How i convert this tag in html to @Html.DropDownList ?

```html
 <select class="selectpicker input-price" data-live-search="true" data-width="100%"
   data-toggle="tooltip" title="Select">
    <option>Select City</option>
    <option>Test1</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```

i can not set data-live-search and data-width to @Html.DropDownList

Thanks For Help

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.YourProperty, Model.YourSelectList, new { data_live_search = true, data_width = "100%", data_toggle = "tooltip", title = "Select" })` (use underscore, not hyphen)

Comment: this work , thank you stephen

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing for a drop down list:

**Controller code**:

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    Contact homeViewModel = new Contact();
    homeViewModel.subject = new List<Subject>();
    homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 1, subject1 = "General Customer Service" });
    homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 2, subject1 = "Suggestions" });
    homeViewModel.subject.Add(new Subject { Id = 3, subject1 = "Product Support" });

    homeViewModel.Selectedid = 1; //this sets the default value for your dropdown

    return View(homeViewModel);
}
```

**Model code**:

```
public class Contact
{   
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill the following")]
  public string name { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Correct Username")]
  [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email id")]
  public string email { get; set; }
  public List<Subject> subject { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage="Please fill the following")]
  public string message { get; set; }
  public int Selectedid { get; set; }
}
```

**View code**:

```
 @model programname.model.Contact

 @Html.DropDownList("Selectedid", new SelectList(Model.subject, "Id",    "subject1", Model.Selectedid), new { @class = "form-control", id = "subject", required = "required" }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with OP's question? Are you trying to ask a new question?